# C++ Class pointer dynamic array deallocate problem

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define ROW 1

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
        this->dummy = new unsigned int[100];
    }
    ~Foo()
    {
        delete[] this->dummy;
        this->dummy = NULL;
    }

    unsigned int* dummy;
};

Foo** allocate()
{
    Foo** foo_array = NULL;
    foo_array = new Foo * [ROW]; //Create space for Foo addresses (row)

    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
        foo_array[i] = new Foo; //Create and allocate Foo for each address space(col)

    return foo_array;
}

int deallocate(Foo* foo_array[ROW])
{
    if (foo_array != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
            delete foo_array[i];
        delete[] foo_array;
        
        foo_array = NULL;

        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

void main()
{
    Foo** foo_array = NULL;

    foo_array = allocate();
    deallocate(foo_array);
    
    if (foo_array != NULL)
        printf("not null something wrong\n");
    system("pause");
}
```

In main() function, foo_array should be pointed to NULL as soon as the deallocation is performed by the deallocate(Foo* foo_array[ROW]) function.

but, In deallocate(Foo* foo_array[ROW]) function,

```
foo_array = NULL;
```

It seems point to NULL by above syntax, however in main() function,
foo_array is not point to NULL.

so, I tried to change above syntax in deallocate(Foo* foo_array[ROW]) function,

```
foo_array = NULL; => (*foo_array) = NULL;
```

It spits out write access violation errors.

Where did it go wrong?

Comment: Why the C tag? This is clearly C++. C is a different language, it does not have classes.

Comment: Parameters are passed as a copy unless you explicitely pass the address of a variable or a reference which you don't.

Comment: @Gerhardh I knew the array as a reference transfer method not a copy value transfer method...

Comment: @Thomas Sablik ok,its working but im confused. whats difference between parameter `Foo*& foo_array` and parameter `Foo* foo_array[ROW]`?

Comment: You do not pass an array but a pointer. The pointer is passed as a copy. Assigning `NULL` to the copy does mit change the value outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any reason to declare `foo_array` as pointer to pointer. In your code you are passing pointers by value. That means you can change what the pointers are pointing at but you can't change the values of the pointers. You can solve the problem using references.

```
#include <cstdio>

#define ROW 1

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
        this->dummy = new unsigned int[100];
    }
    ~Foo()
    {
        delete[] this->dummy;
        this->dummy = NULL;
    }

    unsigned int *dummy;
};

void allocate(Foo *&foo_array)
{
    foo_array = new Foo[ROW];
}

void deallocate(Foo *&foo_array)
{
    delete[] foo_array;
    foo_array = nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    Foo *foo_array = nullptr;

    allocate(foo_array);
    deallocate(foo_array);
    
    if (foo_array != nullptr)
        printf("not null something wrong\n");
}
```

Of course you can make your code much simpler using STL containers or smart pointers

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax would be `foo_array = deallocate (foo_array);` and your `deallocate` should return `NULL`.